# $G(B) = \{k \in \Bbb{Z} : \#(A+k) \cap B = \infty \text{ whenever } \#(A \cap B) = \infty\, A \subset \Bbb{Z}\}$ is a group. Question...

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, ideals

Let $B \subset \Bbb{Z}$ be any infinite subset.  Define $G(B) = \{k \in \Bbb{Z} : \#(A+k) \cap B = \infty \text{ whenever } \#(A \cap B) = \infty\, A \subset \Bbb{Z}\}$.  It forms an additive subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$.  Let $P^2 = \{pq \in \Bbb{Z}: p,q \text{ prime}\}$.  How do I prove that $1 \in G(P^2)$, which amounts to saying $\#(A + 1) \cap P^2 = \infty$ whenever $\# A\cap P^2 = \infty$?

Comment: SInce $\;\Bbb Z=\langle 1\rangle\;$ , what you want to prove is equivalent to $\;G(P^2)=\Bbb Z\;$ , if all what you say is accurate. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be prime and  $A=pP$, in which case clearly $A\cap P$ is infinite. 
Then $A+p\cap P^2$ is finite because $pq+p=p(q+1)$ is in $P^2$ is only possible with $q=2$. We conclude $p\notin G(P^2)$. As $G(P^2)$ is additive we conclude $1\notin G(B)$.

(Inspired by *Igor Rivin*'s answer): Let $n\in \Bbb N$ be composite. Then there are infinitely many primes $\equiv 1\pmod n$
Let $A$ be the set of products of two such primes, an infinite subset of $P^2$.
Then $A+n-1$ contains only multiples of $n$ and at most one of these multiples is the product of two primes.
We conclude that $G(B)$ contains no positive composite integers. As $a\in G(B)$ implies that the composite $6|a|$ is $\in G(B)$, we conclude
$$ G(P^2)=\{0\}.$$

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Let $A$ be the set of products $p q,$ where $p, q$ are prime, and $p\equiv 1 \mod 4,$ $q\equiv 3 \mod 4.$ Then, every element in $A+1$ is divisible by $4,$ and so is not in $P^2.$